# Automatic interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces aren't working

Tags: networking, network-manager, ppp

Despite adding `auto wlan0` or `auto ppp0` to my `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration, these interfaces don't seem to want to come online at boot time.

I got this issue initially when I was using WiFi but I thought it was a one-off issue. I fixed it by adding `allow-hotplug wlan0` like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    ...
```

But now I'm trying to add my Adafruit FONA's `ppp` connection at boot time with the following code that they recommend in the [user manual](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black.pdf) under Automatic PPP Connection On Boot:

```
auto fona
iface fona inet ppp
    provider fona
```

But I get nothing at boot time. As soon as I type `ifup fona`, it works and pulls up a connection just fine.

#### Bonus question:

Is there a nice way to manage such a `ppp` connection so that it will automatically redial when disconnected and such? I'm using NetworkManager but I can't work out how to make this happen.

Comment: For the bonus question, I've found that ModemManager is probably the way to go, but I can't find how to manually add a modem without using the GUI. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I figured out how to get ModemManager to pick up serial devices. See this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/740584/enabling-serial-network-devices-with-modemmanager/740585