# Enabling serial network devices with ModemManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, serial-port, modem-manager

When enabling ModemManager, I don't see my serial-based SIM808 FONA in the list of available modems even though I'm able to get it working with `pppd`.

If I start ModemManager with `service stop ModemManager && ModemManager --debug` I see that it scans past serial devices when searching for modems but for every device I see:

```
modem-manager: (tty/ttyO4): port's parent platform driver is not whitelisted
```

Looking at the source code, I see that it checks the device for the `udev` flag `ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE`. If this flag does not exist, the serial port will not be scanned. It also checks for the `ID_MM_CANDIDATE` flag to see if it's a supported port further up, so I know it's at least able to read that.

So I added this flag as a new rule in a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/78-mm-uart4-enable.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyO4", ENV{ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE}="1"
```

After reboot, I see this in `udevadm info /dev/ttyO4`

```
P: /devices/ocp.3/481a8000.serial/tty/ttyO4
N: ttyO4
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyO4
E: DEVPATH=/devices/ocp.3/481a8000.serial/tty/ttyO4
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE=1
E: MAJOR=247
E: MINOR=4
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=30104
```

But I still get the same error from `modem-manager` even though I clearly have the flag set. How do I whitelist `ttyO4` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source code, the first check for `ID_MM_CANDIDATE` is done on the *port* (i.e. `/dev/ttyO4`). After this, ModemManager will retrieve the physical platform device (the serial port itself) which we can see is `/devices/ocp.3/481a800.serial`, and then check this for the `ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE` flag.

If instead the `udev` rule is changed to

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="481a800.serial", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_PROCESS}="1"
```

then ModemManager will correctly see the flag on the *parent* device (note: ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE doesn't exist anymore).

```
# udevadm info /sys/devices/ocp.3/481a8000.serial
P: /devices/ocp.3/481a8000.serial
E: DEVPATH=/devices/ocp.3/481a8000.serial
E: DRIVER=omap_uart
E: ID_MM_PLATFORM_DRIVER_PROBE=1
E: MODALIAS=of:NserialT<NULL>Cti,omap3-uart
E: OF_COMPATIBLE_0=ti,omap3-uart
E: OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
E: OF_FULLNAME=/ocp/serial@481a8000
E: OF_NAME=serial
E: SUBSYSTEM=platform
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=990701
```

The device now appears in `mmcli -L` and `nmcli device status`.